# Configuration for public (external) access to ubuntu guest on ESXI 5

Tags: ubuntu, routing, port-forwarding, nat, esxi

I am setting up a demo system on a leased dedicated server. System consists of :

- ESXI host with 1 NIC assigned (so 1 Static IP)
- 64 bit Ubuntu guest as server

I installed and configured the system and the current network topology has :

- physical adapter
- A management network where I see the public IP assigned that is given to me by dedicated server provider
- Virtual Machine Port Group where my guest is running
- Finally a vSwitch between physical adapter and networks mentioned above

I can access to ESXI host, from the vSphere client I can access my Ubuntu guest as well. Guest has access to web (verified by pinging).

**My question :**
What kind of basic setup would allow external users to access services running on the Ubuntu guest ?

Before asking this question I browsed a bit and scanned through VMWare documentations. I have seen:

[port forwarding via router](https://superuser.com/questions/379573/vm-on-esxi-host-how-does-one-make-externally-accessible) however I do not have control over the router.

[using pfSense](https://serverfault.com/questions/353223/recommended-way-to-setup-a-secure-esxi-environment-with-a-publicly-accessible-ra) well this one is looking like a solution but a bit more complicated then I expected.

Are there any simpler ways to accomplish my goal ?

Note : I am a software developer with a bit familiarity of computer networks, virtualization and linux. Therefore I would really appreciate simple solutions (if possible), explanations/directions on the topic.

Comment: Are you referring to the graphical(GUI) guest login? Or some other services like http?

Comment: Indeed I am referring to http and other stuff. I will deploy a web applicaton.
Besides, at the moment I can access guest only via vSphere client. Guest's ip 192.168.x.x. Therefore there is no way of accessing to it directly (externally).

Comment: (1) Is that 192.168.x.x IP a LAN ip reachable inside your network? (2) Are those services accessible within your network? If (1) & (2) are true, we only have to configure the router for port forwarding, or pfsense, if that is the only one we have control.

Comment: As I stated router is not under my control. And yes, both 1&2 are true. However, I've found the pfsense option complicated and asked my question to double check if there are no other solutions. Rationale behind my question : is pfsense the only option. If yes, why ? If no, what are other options. Less complicated solutions are appreciated.

Comment: That pfsense link may not be your answer. (3) Is the host 1 static IP referred in the question an external IP?

Comment: Yes, host has an external IP. It is a leased dedicated server running on the network of the provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### vSwitches

It is doable, but the bad news is vSwitches till today still don't support NAT. So some kind of setup like pfSense VM as a routing front end is needed.

**pfSense Alternative**

On the other hand, pfSense is not the only choice, you can use a plain linux(eg, Ubuntu server) VM with iptables to do the job.

### Additional IP - Simplest Way

Another choice is get additional IP and setup VM to use bridge mode, which is the easiest. But may (very likely) come with additional cost.

Comment: I'm currently negotiating for the additional IP. It seems like a solution. Once it is set I will be back and share the result